# Apex method receives null

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class

Hi everybody I am trying to pass a wrapper from LWC to an apex class. The wrapper in js has the structure of the Apex class and the method that receives this wrapper is:

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static void getInfoFromLWC(WrapperC111 wrapperWithInfo){
    System.debug('what comes from LWC... '+ wrapperWithInfo);
}
```

and the in my js I have the next method that is triggered when the user clicks the validate button:

```
    data;
error;
handleValidacion(event){
    const inputs = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input', 'lightning-combobox')]
    console.log('inside button handler');

    inputs.forEach((input) => input.reportValidity());

    if(!inputs.every((input)=>input.checkValidity())){
        return;
    }

    console.log('whats inside the wrapper...'+ this.createWrapperJSON );

    wrapperC101({wrapperWithInfo : this.createWrapper()}).then((result) =>{
        this.data = result;
        this.error = undefined;
    }).catch((error)=>{
        this.error = error;
        this.data = undefined;
    })

}
```

and then the createWrapperMethod createds the wrapper with the user data:

```
createWrapperJSON;
createWrapper(){
    console.log('inside the wrapper ');
    this.createWrapperJSON = {
            data: {
                requestData: {
                    indicator: this.indicator,
                   
                },
                cliente:{
                    Id: {
                        Person: this.Person
                    },
                    Name:{
                        Name: this.name,
                        firstName: this.firstName,
                    },
                    Phone:
                        [
                            {prefixCountry: this.prefix1,
                                number: this.number1
                            },
                            {prefixCountry: this.prefix2,
                                number: this.number3
                            },
                            {prefixCountry: this.prefix3,
                                number: this.number3
                            },
                            {prefixCountry: this.prefix4,
                                number: this.number4
                            },
                            {prefixCountry: this.prefix5,
                                number: this.number5
                            },
                        ]
                    ,
                    email: this.email,
                    
                },
                comments: this.comments,
                documents: this.iterator,
            }
    }
console.log('result wrapper... '+ JSON.stringify(this.createWrapperJSON));
//return this.createWrapperJSON;
stringToReturn = JSON.stringify(this.createWrapperJSON);
return stringToReturn
}
```

The problem is that when I check in the console it says '"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 2099646736-25205 (-97864558)"' and in other tries in the developer console the System.debug  from the apex method says that the incoming wrapper is null
Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the wrapper definition in the question? I would like to see them because it is important to add get and set in the variables of the wrapper so that when you pass it, values get assigned to it in apex.

Comment: Could you please share the code of the wrapper from the Apex side?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing wrapper after stringify it, you need to change your apex function declaration

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static void getInfoFromLWC(String wrapperWithInfo){
    System.debug('what comes from LWC... '+ wrapperWithInfo);
}
```

Or instead of

```
stringToReturn = JSON.stringify(this.createWrapperJSON);
return stringToReturn
```

Do this

```
    return this.createWrapperJSON
```